# GWT DOM catching drag and drop browser event

Tags: html, gwt, dom

Using Firefox and maybe others modern browsers, we are allowed to select some text of a page, and then `Drag and Drop` our selection.

The destination of this drag and drop, can be any HTML input, or even the bar address, the search field, etc.

I would like to know if this kind of `drag event` is handled by the browser in a special way, or if it is possible to capture this (a `DOM` event or something like that).

To be more specific, I'm trying to add this drop functionality to some `GWT` objects and then be able to retrieve the selected text.

I'm using GWT.

**EDIT, WORKING SOLUTION**

This is some relevant code :

```
TextArea text = new TextArea();
SimplePanel panel = new SimplePanel(text);

TextArea text2 = new TextArea();
SimplePanel panel2 = new SimplePanel(text2);

Button button = new Button("button");
button.addDragOverHandler(new DragOverHandler()
{
     @Override
     public void onDragOver(DragOverEvent event)
     {
         GWT.log("onDragOver");
     });

 RootPanel.get().add(panel);
 RootPanel.get().add(panel2);
 RootPanel.get().add(button);
```

Image :

[image: Image showing the behavior]

The use of the button is just an example.

The goal here is to retrieve the text `I want to drop this text over the button` through some handlers on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT has built-in support for *native drag and drop*.

According to your description, you seem to be looking for widgets implementing [`HasDropHandlers`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasDropHandlers.html), and there are a bit more than a few ;-)

It's also rather easy to add it to a custom widget (have a look at how it's done in built-in widgets, such as `FocusPanel` or `Grid`)

Comment: I've tried that interfaces, and some others, but I didn't succeed. I've updated my question. Maybe what I'm trying to achieve is beyond the laws of nature.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried? You might have to add a `DragOverHandler` to set the _effect allowed_ to something else than `none` and cancel the event, for the `DropEvent` to be dispatched to your `DropHandler`.